# Safe way to render user content in Angular2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have two Angular 2 apps: one for end-users and one for an editorial team.
Both are written in Javascript.

The end-user app basically is a WhatsApp-like chat view, where a user can chat with the editorial team 1-on-1. The editorial app shows a list of all conversations, and also has a WhatsApp-like chat view for each conversation.

So far, so good. Everything works fine. I have a question regarding safety however. In a first version, the content of a message in the editorial app was rendered using the innerHTML statement:

```
<div [innerHTML]="message.data.text"></div>
```

When a user abuses the chat input field, however, and types in

## message

, this HTML statement is rendered, which is what we don't want (because it could lead to malicious attempts with script tags etcetera). I noticed, however, that Angular2 is smart enough not to render JavaScript, but I'm not sure if every kind of code injection is covered. So I changed this to:

```
<div>{{ message.data.text }}</div>
```

This ignores all HTML and renders

<h1>message</h1>

Is this a safe way to do this? Or are there still some culprits? I guess the best way to tackle this problem, is to filter out all unsafe input in the backend (is there a reliable way to do that?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try filling in a script tag, and will find out it doesn't render anymore, and throws a warning in the console. Same goes if you use the `[innerHtml]` binding, and try to create an `<input>` tag. This will fail as well.

> To systematically block XSS bugs, Angular treats all values as untrusted by default. When a value is inserted into the DOM from a template, via property, attribute, style, class binding, or interpolation, Angular sanitizes and escapes untrusted value

Read the [**security**](https://angular.io/guide/security) section of the angular guide for more information.

But if you really do not want the user to generate any `HTML`, you should always use the interpolation binding (`{{text}}`).

Interpolated content is always escaped—the HTML isn't interpreted and the browser displays angle brackets in the element's text content.

For the HTML to be interpreted, bind it to an HTML property such as `innerHTML`. But binding a value that an attacker might control into `innerHTML` normally causes an XSS vulnerability.